# Count of Each Element in 2d NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine you have a 2D-array (as a NumPy `int` array) like:

```
[[2,2,3,3],
 [2,3,3,3],
 [3,3,4,4]]
```

Now you want to get an array of the same shape, but instead of the original values, you want to replace the number by its occurrences. Which means, the number 2 changes to 3, since it occurred 3 times, the 3s become 7s and the 4s become 2s.

So the output would be:

```
[[3,3,7,7],
 [3,7,7,7],
 [7,7,2,2]]
```

My solution was first to create a dictionary, which saves all original values as keys and as values the number of occurrences. But for arrays of shape 2000x2000, this seemed to be quite slow.

How could I achieve this more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, the flattened version of the array is sorted.  Will this always be the case?

Comment: Nope, the array was not meant to be sorted. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should be able to stay in NumPy here by using `return_inverse` within `np.unique()`:

> If True, also return the indices of the unique array (for the
>   specified axis, if provided) that can be used to reconstruct `ar`.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[2,2,3,3],
...               [2,3,3,3],
...               [3,3,4,4]])

>>> _, inv, cts = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
>>> cts[inv].reshape(a.shape)

array([[3, 3, 7, 7],
       [3, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 2, 2]])
```

This will also work for the case where the flattened array is not sorted, such as `b = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [4, 4, 1]])`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `numpy.unique` to extract value counts.

Then convert to a dictionary and use `numpy.vectorize` to utilise this dictionary mapping.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2,2,3,3],
              [2,3,3,3],
              [3,3,4,4]])

d = dict(zip(*np.unique(A.ravel(), return_counts=True)))

res = np.vectorize(d.get)(A)

array([[3, 3, 7, 7],
       [3, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

**Performance**

I see the above method takes ~2s for a 2000x2000 array versus 3s via a `collections.Counter` dictionary-based method. But pure `numpy` solutions by [PaulPanzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961492/9209546) and [BradSolomon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961206/9209546) are faster still.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2000, 2000))
MAX_LOOKUP = 2**24

def map_count(A):
    d = dict(zip(*np.unique(A.ravel(), return_counts=True)))
    return np.vectorize(d.get)(A)

def map_count2(A):
    d = Counter(A.ravel())
    return np.vectorize(d.get)(A)

def bs(A):
    _, inv, cts = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    return cts[inv].reshape(A.shape)

def pp(a):
    mn, mx = a.min(), a.max()
    span = mx-mn+1
    if span > MAX_LOOKUP:
        raise RuntimeError('values spread to wide')
    a = a - mn
    return np.bincount(a.ravel(), None, span)[a]

%timeit map_count(A)   # 1.9 s ± 24.2 ms per loop
%timeit map_count2(A)  # 3 s ± 33.1 ms per loop
%timeit bs(A)          # 887 ms ± 20 ms per loop
%timeit pp(A)          # 149 ms ± 6.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'd never heard of `np.vectorize` before. It sure sounds pretty neat.

Comment: It sounds good, but it's not. Because it's not actually "vectorized" - it just loops through every item and applies a function. More a convenience than actually improving performance.

Comment: Ah for some reason, I assumed it looked at the code graph and actually vectorized it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that takes advantage of the fact that your values are int:

```
MAX_LOOKUP = 2**24

def f_pp(a):
    mn, mx = a.min(), a.max()
    span = mx-mn+1
    if span > MAX_LOOKUP:
        raise RuntimeError('values spread to wide')
    a = a - mn
    return np.bincount(a.ravel(), None, span)[a]
```

Timings (heavily based on @jpp's work):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=3)
>>> 
>>> for l, r in [(0, 10), (0, 1000), (-8000000, 8000000)]:
...     a = np.random.randint(l, r, (2000, 2000))
...     print(l, r)
...     print('mc ', timeit('map_count(a)', **kwds))
...     print('mc2', timeit('map_count2(a)', **kwds))
...     print('bs ', timeit('bs(a)', **kwds))
...     print('pp ', timeit('f_pp(a)', **kwds))
... 
0 10
mc  2.462232475867495
mc2 3.820418732939288
bs  1.266723491018638
pp  0.11216754489578307
0 1000
mc  2.972961534978822
mc2 4.3769155589398
bs  2.1607728030066937
pp  0.14146877988241613
-8000000 8000000
mc  10.753600731957704
mc2 8.373655589064583
bs  2.700256273150444
pp  0.7070535880047828
```

Comment: Can you explain (briefly) why we see such a massive improvement from your algorithm?

Comment: @jpp `bincount` as long as the number of bins is not excessively large is O(n) and in my experience just a pretty fast function. `unique` does a sort under the hood, so is O(n log n).

Comment: Thanks - this deserves to be the accepted answer!